# I have an hw.1 I want to access

Tags: wallet

I have an HW.1 I had lost and finally found.  I tried to access but the new ledger software does not work.  i tried with electrum, but have managed to lock myself out of pin attempts.

What can I do to recover my bitcoin from this device?  I have searched and can't seem to find much on it.

Answer (score 1):

> **What can I do to recover my bitcoin from this device?**

If the device believes it is in the hands of thieves (many failed PINs) it should never divulge its contents to anyone under any circumstances. I don't know much about the HW 1 but I'd hope (and you should too) it would either self destruct or require some sort of full-reset to be usable again - losing all its contents in the reset process.

The way to recover control over the money is to use the recovery words you wrote down and kept safe back when you first set-up the device.

As [one reviewer](https://www.techradar.com/uk/reviews/ledger-hw1) said in 2016:

> The on-boarding process is quick and easy, asking the user to pick a four-digit PIN and to **write down a series of ‘recovery words’ on a bundled informational sheet**.

> These words allow the wallet to be regenerated onto a replacement HW.1 should you lose or damage your original, and represent the device’s weakest link. When you’ve recorded the words, the card should be sealed away in a safe and treated with the same care you would furnish upon a stack of banknotes to the value of your Bitcoin hoard.

[Ledger no longer provide support for the HW 1](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010500620-Discontinued-products) but [the recovery words will work with later Ledger devices](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005434914-Restore-from-recovery-phrase).